# Pintar pixeis em c++

Tags: c++, mingw

Olá, eu precisava de uma função para pintar pixeis na consola.
Eu arranjei uma solução [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378642/c-pixels-in-console-window) mas ao compilar dá-me o seguinte erro:

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccORhjHu.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `SetPixel@16'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Gostaria que me fornecessem uma maneira para corrigir este erro ou uma outra forma de fazer a mesma coisa.
**Nota:** Eu uso windows 7 32-bits, com o mingw c++ instalado

Comment: Você incluiu a *libgdi32.a* na compilação (com `-lgdi32`)?

Comment: Eu incluo essa flag mas dá um outro erro. Dá este erro: **undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::Init()'**

Comment: Qual é o comando completo que você está utilizando para compilar?

Comment: gcc filename.cpp -lgdi32 e inclui a biblioteca unistd.h e substitui `cin.ignore();` por `sleep(5);` porque me estava a dar erro

Comment: O programa não é em C++? Se for, a linha deveria ser `g++ filename......`. O *gcc* é para programas em C, não C++

Comment: Muito obrigado! Resultou, só uma coisa, gcc deveria funcionar porque cpp é C Plus Plus (C++). Podia transformar esse comentário numa resposta para a marcar como correta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme os comentários,o erro foi corrigido após incluir a lib GDI32 (`libgdi32.a`), onde fica localizada a função `SetPixel`.

O erro:

```
undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
```

ocorreu devido ao uso do compilador `gcc` (utilizado para compilar programas em `C`).

O compilador correto para a linguagem C++ no pacote *Mingw32* é o: `g++`.